# Error while loading shared libraries

Tags: command-line, libraries

I'm using a software called GPUOcelot in order to be able to compile a software that I'm programming that uses CUDA. But my computer doesn't have any NVIDIA card, so that's the reason why I am using this emulator, but when I execute the next command:

```
g++ -o Sinulacionpositrones.out Simulacionpositrones.o OcelotConfig -l
```

I obtain this:

```
OcelotConfig: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.46.1: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What can I do? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. The webpage is this:
https://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/

Comment: Whats the output of `sudo updatedb && locate "libboost_system.so"`?

Comment: Here is your library with many many dependencies: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost1.46-all-dev

Answer (score 5):

**Create a symbolic link**

- If you have the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.55.0`

  64-bit

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.55.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.46.1
  ```

  32-bit

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.55.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.46.1
  ```
- If you have the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0`

  64-bit

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.46.1
  ```

  32-bit

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.46.1
  ```

---

Alternative

Download and install the packages from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost1.46-all-dev).

Answer (score 1):

Ocelot is looking for an older version of boost. You'll either have to create a ton of symlinks to get Ocelot to think it's the right version or downgrade boost.

Here's a link to getting a specific version of  [boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759434/boost-installation) .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @muru I think this is an answer beyond the link..

Comment: @muru thanks for pointing that out, I'll try to make a more comprehensive answer next time